# getElementById no funciona

Tags: javascript

¿Alguien ve el error?

En el index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div>
    <p>Introduce los valores:</p>
    <input  type="text" name="arrayInput" id="arrayInput">
    <a id="butt" href='#' >Enviar</a>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Y en mi js:

```
console.log('ok!');

const button = document.getElementById('butt');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
    if (button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', recogerInput);
    } else {
      console.log('No lo encuentro');
    }
  }
```

Me devuelve el else...

Necesito algo tan simple como que me añada el click al botón, pero no entiendo por qué no lo encuentra ni con getElementById ni con querySelectorAll...

Comment: Falta que agregues la función `recogerInput` y listo. Pero no entiendo por qué tanto lío para agregar un *listener* ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer en concreto y por qué usarías dos funciones para un simple *listener*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me funciona perfectamente, el unico error que me daba es que la funcion `recogerInput` no existia, la agregue y aqui esta el ejemplo. Te recomiendo ponerlo antes del `</body>` para que al momento que cargue tu archivo .js el DOM este completamente cargado.

```js
console.log('ok!');

const button = document.getElementById('butt');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
    if (button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', recogerInput);
    } else {
      console.log('No lo encuentro');
    }
  }
  function recogerInput(){
  console.log("Hey")
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div>
    <p>Introduce los valores:</p>
    <input  type="text" name="arrayInput" id="arrayInput">
    <a id="butt" href='#' >Enviar</a>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! El problema era ese, la colocación del tag script.

Answer (score 1):

El problema, como ya se ha dicho, era que no estaba creado el *handler* (`recogerInput`) que estabas asignando al evento.

Visto eso, te recomendaría que implementes buenas prácticas en tu código:

1. Deberías comprobar que el DOM está cargado antes de referirte a cualquier parte de él. Puedes hacerlo [agregando un *listener*  a `DOMContentLoaded`, tal y como explica MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).
2. No tiene sentido marear tanto el código, usando dos funciones para agregar un listener. Lo correcto sería simplemente asignar el *listener*  una vez que el DOM se haya cargado, porque es lo que certifica que el elemento se encontrará sí o sí. Si se trata de elementos *dinámicos*, entonces puedes asignarles una clase, y luego usar `querySelectorAll` u otro para asignar el listener a los elementos de esa clase.

Hay que optar por la simplicidad en el código, o puedes encontrarte tarde o temprano en medio de un plato de spaghetti.

```js
/*TODO manipulación de elementos del DOM debería ir dentro de este bloque*/
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  /*
    Crea una referencia sólo ni necesitas 
    referirte a este elemento más adelante
    sino puedes hacer una asignación directa con:
    document.getElementById('butt')..addEventListener('click', recogerInput);
  */
  const button = document.getElementById('butt');
  button.addEventListener('click', recogerInput);
});

function recogerInput(e) {
  console.log("ocurrió click en "+e.target.text);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Introduce los valores:</p>
  <input type="text" name="arrayInput" id="arrayInput">
  <a id="butt" href='#'>Enviar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Tienes razón, tengo un montón de código de más. En cuanto a comprobar la carga del DOM... veo que es algo similar a jQuery. Nunca lo había hecho con javascript puro. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @InfiniteRoads jQuery no más que una librería basada en Javascript. Siempre que se pueda es mucho  mejor usar Javascript puro, es como la diferencia entre usar el original y una copia basada en él.